# Facebook, Twitter icon not showing in UIActivityViewController on iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have added this code for presenting a `UIActivityViewController`:

```
-(IBAction)activityAction:(id)sender
{
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello Welcome!",[UIImage imageNamed:@"scene3.jpg"],nil] applicationActivities:nil];

     activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Facebook, Twitter and Weibo icons are not showing in iOS7. In iOS6, all the icons are showing correctly. See the screenshot below:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue...have you figure it out?

Comment: No. i didn't check in device. but it is not working in simulator.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're probably not logged in to Facebook or Twitter in the devices Settings.  They won't show up here unless the user is logged in.  File a bug with Apple.

Comment: Marty is right. Unless your credentials are not there in settings icon wont show up in UIActivityViewController in iOS7. Why did Apple do such change, so bad of them

Comment: I am facing the same issue and i can see that facebook icon in  apple's Photo Application.Any idea help would be appreciated @Marty

Comment: Is there any other way (using fb sdk for ios), if I am not login?

Comment: Do you have the solution for IOS 10 with the same issue  with this?

Comment: Do you have solution for this issue in IOS 10?

Answer (score 28):

Look at the name of the property `excludedActivityTypes`, you are **excluding** facebook, twitter, ...

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
```

excludes only Weibo and Assign to contact

Comment: Test it on a real device

Comment: Facebook and Twitter won't show up on the simulator. And other options may show, but they won't work (e.g. Mail, text Message)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you don't exclude the Activities that you want to use. 
So, remove "UIActivityTypePostToFacebook" & "UIActivityTypePostToTwitter" from "activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes" object.

Also, Make sure that you are logged in into Facebook and Twitter accounts in order to post on respective social platform.

Please note that this is working on simulator and real devices.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code,

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
```

Change to this,

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
```

And if you have to logged into facebook, twitter on your device settings. Then only it will be visible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Don't include UIActivityTypePostToFacebook in

```
       activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,   UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```