# UIActivityViewController when have no Facebook account in settings

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController, I want to show Facebook option even if the user has not defined a Facebook account in device settings.

In my code, Facebook option not shown when there is no Facebook acoount in settings.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But, in Safari or more apps there is Facebook option and when click on it - a alert is displayed with "No facebbok account" title and message says "go to settings".

There is any way to add Facebook like this or this possible just for apple apps?

[image: No Facebook Account]

Comment: good question, I want to know the same.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do that using `UIActivityViewController`. If you check other apps (no apple development) you can see that doesn't use `UIActivityViewController` but Action Sheets or something else and uses Social Framework. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956620/facebook-twitter-icon-not-showing-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-on-ios7). And check this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/) if you use Social Framework.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please avoid using txt-speak.

Comment: thanks for the tutorial link, but using social framework still doesn't prompt the user to go to the settings to sign in for FB for example, if they're not already. is there really no way to show an option for FB and prompt the user to go to settings???

Comment: You have to use Social Framework, it's the only way.. See This video! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iCiP0GO7po