# UIActivityViewController - Facebook/Twitter not showing in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios

I've set up my UIActivityViewController and mail shows up. But I can't figure out how to get Facebook/Twitter to work? I have read somewhere that since obviously the Xcode doesn't have Facebook/Twitter signed in, iOS7 doesn't show the app?

My code:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[@"Hello"];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: have you sign in your twitter or facebook in Settings?

Comment: I've been looking everywhere in xcode but I am unable to find where?

Comment: just in your Simulator's Settings app.

Comment: I'm not sure where you mean? I've checked all the tabs and I can't find anywhere to add this in. If you're meaning have I signed into facebook / twitter. I am unable to as the application doesn't show

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19034338/544265

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook, Twitter icon not showing in UIActivityViewController on iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956620/facebook-twitter-icon-not-showing-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-on-ios7)