# UIActivityController not showing Facebook, Twitter, etc

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

iOS 7, Xcode 5

I've setup a UIActivityController in my app and no matter what I do, I can't ever see the icons for Twitter, Facebook, etc. I only see Mail and Message.
This happens both in the Simulator and on my iPhone 5S.

I've tried third-party tutorials and sample code and get the same behavior. However, when I use Safari/Yahoo on my iPhone, I can see everything, even though I do not have accounts for everything.

The code is straightforward:

```
NSString *text = @"How to add Facebook and Twitter sharing to an iOS app";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/02/how-to-add-facebook-and-twitter-sharing-to-an-ios-app/"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"roadfire-icon-square-200"];

UIActivityViewController *controller =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
 initWithActivityItems:@[text, url, image]
 applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My understanding is that I do NOT need to have active accounts on any device to simply see the icons in the Sheet.

So can someone help figure out why this is happening?

Comment: I think you do have to be logged in to see Facebook or twitter.  I ran your code and it does not show fb and tw.  Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956620/facebook-twitter-icon-not-showing-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-on-ios7

Comment: If this is the case, does anyone know why I can see them on my iPhone in Safari/Yahoo? Doesn't make any sense....

Comment: You don't have to be logged in to another account, however, the accounts must be set up on your device for iOS to show their icons.