# iOS: Skype not available in UIActivityViewController for image sharing

Tags: ios, sharing, skype, uiactivityviewcontroller

Unable to share image using UIAcivityViewController on Skype. Also Skype option is not available in Photo app on iPhone, why? Although, all other sharing apps are available.

```
 IImage *img = [self imageWithView:self.viewSubContailer];
 NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"];
 NSArray *arrActivityItems = @[img,str];//
 UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]  initWithActivityItems:arrActivityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[avc setValue:@"Test" forKey:@"subject"];
NSLog(@"self.delegate : %@",self.delegate);
[(TestViewController*)self.delegate presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:(@selector(setCompletionWithItemsHandler:))]){
    [avc setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR ON cancel:%@",activityError);
        [self.delegate cancelSharingAction];

    }];

}else{
    [avc setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        [self.delegate cancelSharingAction];
    }];
}
```

Comment: this may help try login to skype then check showing option or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956620/facebook-twitter-icon-not-showing-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-on-ios7

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm already logged in.

Comment: you also not added skype in excludedActivityTypes?please share your code of uiactivityviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

you can share to skype or Image or String - when you send both it takes only the string:\